# Product of subset of numbers in python

Tags: python

I'm going through project euler, and i'm getting stuck on this question.

I'm going to post my code with comments, so everyone can follow my thinking and see where I went wrong. All suggestions are appreciated :)

```
# need to find the largest product in a series

import time # brings time into the code

start = time.time() # creates a start time for the code

list = [] # where I'm going to store the multipules

# the '\ takes the grid and converts it into one long number'

num = '\
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450' 

i = 0 # start of the ticker

for i in range(0, 1000, 1): # the length of the large block of numbers is 1000

    hold_num = int(num[i])*int(num[i+1])*int(num[i+2]) # im creating a number of every three consecutive numbers ... this is the subset
    list.append(hold_num) # storing the products in a list
    i =+ 1

print max(list) # finding the max of the products in the stored list
```

I end up getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/robertdefilippi/Documents/Python/Euler/8eu.py", line 37, in <module>
    hold_num = int(num[i])*int(num[i+1])*int(num[i+2])
IndexError: string index out of range
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `num[i+2]` when i is 1000 is the problem.loop till 998.

Comment: Consider using `zip(num, num[1:], num[2:])` to get a list of all 3-tuples without worrying about the end special problems.  Try it with `num = range(10)` to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `for i in range(0, 1000, 1)`, reaching 999, `num[i+1]` and `num[i+2]` will be out range.

You have to use `range(0,998,1)` instead. Which can be shortened to `range(998)`. And doing this, `i` will be incremented and starts at 0. You don't need to do `i+=1` or `i=0`.

Comment: Using that `998` is not a good style; don't compute while programming, let the computer do it for you.  In fact, your way it is a hidden code doubling because that 998 is directly derived from the 1000 and the 3 (and the off-by-one effect).  So in case the code gets changed to not facilitate a 3 but a 6, then you'd have to adjust your 998 to a 995 and probably that will be forgotten.